# "Choose an Application" dialog is mostly blank; can it be fixed?

Tags: kubuntu

Kubuntu 21.10

Most of the categories in the "Choose an Application" dialog are empty, though the relevant programs show up with they're selected. How can I fix this?

[image: Choose an Application]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) We can't accept bug reports here. FYI: 21.10 will be EOL in a week. It's strongly recommended that you upgrade or replace it before this happens.

Comment: I would not waste your time reporting a bug on 21.10 as changes require SRU, and the notice has already gone out that SRU's are *unwanted* for that release unless absolutely critical to security (*your issue won't apply!*) as there is **less** than a week left; and if you were aware, a number of updates were still in queues for 21.04 when it reached EOL which created problems in closing the repository. They don't want to repeat that with 21.10!.  EOL warning notices went out awhile ago, eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: AHA. Didn't know it was that close to upgrade. Roger that. Maybe the issue will be addressed.